# Issue when Full page cache enable in magento2

Tags: jquery, magento-2.2.5, full-page-cache

I have found issue related to full page cache enable. I am not able to remove the label on document ready in magento2

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    require(['jquery'], function ($) 
    {
        $(document).ready(function () 
        {
            $("label:contains('Please type captcha here')").remove();
        })
    });
</script>
```

jQuery not working with full page cache

Comment: try to use this : <script type="text/x-magento-init"> instead of this: <script type="text/javascript">

Comment: you can also use timeout function to hide above message after few seconds

Comment: you can flush & refresh the cache after putting this script in your html

Comment: @JimitBhavsar I tried both solution but still not working

Comment: you can use ajax function, you have to create one file in root folder and put your script in that file and call that file using ajax request

Comment: Can u please provide me code for ajax function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39341901/how-to-call-a-php-function-from-ajax